# Manage static Resources in spring mvc

Tags: spring-mvc

I am building an application with Spring MVC and jquery for UI. The UI developer is designing the pages using jQuery without using any server (as it is not required). The pages are integrated by developers in the application. 
The issue here is that the UI designer is using relative directory path and to integrate these pages, paths need to be prefixed with spring resource path. Even the JS and CSS files are referring to images with relative directory path. Every time the UI is update same process is repeated for integration.

What I want to know is there any better approach in this case so that

1. the relative path used by ui developer doesn't needs to be changed every time for integration.
2. The spring static resource loading can still be used. `<mvc:resources mapping="/res/**" location="/resources/" />`
3. The path reference in any js or css file can also work without any changes in it.

I do not want to do anything which tightly couple it with a server. Please help.

Answer (score -1):

lookup util:constant in the spring documentation and see if that is helpful.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion but I am not sure if this will help. I guess it is used to define a constant for a bean in config file. I am looking some way the static path can work without change in js / css file.